# Get Request should return stringify value and assign to a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, get

Here are my methods:

```
function RequestGet(options, url){
    fetch(url, options).then(function(response){
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(value) {
        data = JSON.stringify(value)
        console.log(data)
    }).catch(function() {
        console.log("fail")
    })
}


function GetUUID(){
    data = RequestGet()
    uuid = []
    data2 = data.results[0].groups
    groupLength = data2.length
    for (i = 0; i < groupLength; i++){
        uuid[i] = data2[i].uuid
    }
    uuidString = uuid.toString()
    console.log(uuidString)
}
```

I need RequestGet to return the output of 'data' (which I'm able to view with console.log(data)) so I can use the dictionary in the GetUUID function below to get a specific key (key I'm looking for is uuid).

I just need to be able to pass the GET response to the GetUUID method.

Currently it returns "Undefined"

Thanks.

Comment: You're not returning anything from RequestGet.

Comment: This doesn't work either.


`function RapidproGet(options, url){
    return fetch(url, options).then(function(response){
         return response.json();
     }).then(function(value) {
         data = JSON.stringify(value)
         //console.log(data)
         return data;
     }).catch(function() {
         //console.log("fail")
     })
 }`

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a Promise from your `RequestGet`. Try this:

```
function RequestGet(options, url){
   return fetch(url, options).then(function(response){
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(value) {
        data = JSON.stringify(value)
        console.log(data)
        return data;
    }).catch(function() {
        console.log("fail")
    })
}


async function GetUUID(){
    data = await RequestGet()
    uuid = []
    data2 = data.results[0].groups
    groupLength = data2.length
    for (i = 0; i < groupLength; i++){
        uuid[i] = data2[i].uuid
    }
    uuidString = uuid.toString()
    console.log(uuidString)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function RequestGet(options, url){
    return fetch(url, options).then(function(response){
         return response.json();
     }).then(function(value) {
         data = JSON.stringify(value)
         //console.log(data)
         return data;
     }).catch(function() {
         //console.log("fail")
     })
 }
 
 async function GetUUID(){
    data = await RequestGet()
    console.log(data)
}


RequestGet(options, url)
GetUUID()

Output: Undefined
```
I can see the dict if I uncomment console.log(data)

Comment: Where have you declared `data`, `uuid` etc? Globally?

Comment: Currently I've taken a that out until I'm able to pass the response to the UUID method.

So all I have is this:

`function RequestGet(options, url){
    return fetch(url, options).then(function(response){
         return response.json();
     }).then(function(value) {
         data = JSON.stringify(value)
         //console.log(data)
         return data;
     }).catch(function() {
         //console.log("fail")
     })
 }`


 
 `async function GetUUID(){
    data = await RequestGet()
    console.log(data)
}`

Comment: `async function GetUUID(){
    data = await RequestGet()
    console.log(data)
}`

Comment: Try this simplification: `async function RequestGet(options, url){
   const response = await fetch(url, options);
   const data = await response.json();
   return data;
}`

Comment: It returns “unhandled promise rejection.”

Comment: Then wrap the call in try catch and see what the error message is